# Custom metric not being set or not being adjusted

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is the code to create my tracker and add the metric:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-x', 'none');
  var metricValue = 123;
  ga('set', 'metric1', metricValue);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Code containing the post:

```
function queryReports() {
            gapi.client.request({
                path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
                root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
                method: 'POST',
                body: {
                    reportRequests: [
                        {
                            viewId: VIEW_ID,
                            dateRanges: [
                                {
                                    startDate: '2015-08-19',
                                    endDate: '2016-09-19'
                                }
                            ],
                            metrics: [
                                { expression: "ga:pageviews" },
                                { expression: "ga:timeOnPage" },
                                { expression: "ga:exitRate" },
                                { expression: "ga:pageLoadTime" },
                                { expression: "ga:goal1ConversionRate" },
                                { expression: "ga:goal2ConversionRate" },
                                { expression: "ga:metric1" },
                                { expression: 'ga:sessions'}
                            ] 
                }
            ]
        }
        }).
        then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
        }

        function displayResults(response) {
            var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
            document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
        }
```

I receive all data correctly except the one from the custom metric. I am also not getting the error that the metric does not extist, so it seems to be recongnized. Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious, did you create the custom metric in the property settings ? GA would not give an error message if a metric does not exist, it would simply ignore it.

Comment: @Erike Yup, I've added it and received google analytics code piece to include (which is included up here). And I had gotten some errors before when fiddling around with it, but no errors anymore now.

Comment: @Kai did you ever resolve this?